# Connecting xampp to standalone MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I installed the standalone MySQL server because I needed it on my previous project, now that I started a web based project I need to use Xampp however I am having problem in connecting xampp to my standalone mysql server. What should I do?

I can't open a connection manually in php neither did phpmyadmin it says access denied can't connect: invalid settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I already figured it out by changing the configurations of phpmyadmin

```
change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

I also create a new user in mysql with command
create user 'user'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password'

and setting the phpmyadmin credentials to the user I created